# eclipse cdt debug information

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to use eclipse as C++ IDE.

In eclipse for java developers, when a runtime error occurs, the console prints out the name and stack trace of the exception.

Different from eclipse for java developers, eclipse cdt console gives very little feedback. The console simply says "terminated" in its header when an error is encountered. 
And also,I cant see whether there is a memory leak or not. Am I supposed to adjust some settings? Or eclipse just does not support the fancy functions like it does for java?

Comment: Run the program in a debugger. The should be an icon or menu entry called something like "Debug".